# What happened to the original crew of Destiny?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

After watching the series again, I still can't find the answer to the question, what happened to the original crew of *Destiny*?

Comment: Vaguely related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9633/1167

Answer (score 33):

There was no original crew of the Destiny. It would seem that the Ancients set it (and its [counterparts](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Seed_ship)) off ***unmanned*** with the firm intention of boarding later, then never got around to it after they discovered how to ascend to a higher plane of existence.

> **GLORIA:** *This is what you wanted.*
>
> **RUSH:** *You know, the Ancients never intended Destiny to operate on its own. They were supposed to come here, in person.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SGU: Aftermath - Transcript](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/SGU_2.02_%22Aftermath%22_Transcript)</sup></sub>

and

> **RUSH:** *Look, if Destiny was ever capable of dialing back to Earth, it was thousands of years ago **when the Ancients originally intended to come here.** But not now.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SGU: Water - Transcript](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/SGU_1.06_%22Water%22_Transcript)</sup></sub>

and

> **RUSH:** *The name of the ship, translated from Ancient. I've also discovered that **they were never here.***
>
> **ELI:** *I thought this was an Ancient ship?*
>
> **RUSH:** *It is. But **they sent it out unmanned, planning to use the 'gate to get here when it was far enough out into the universe.** But…they probably learned to ascend before that time.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SGU: Air, Part 2 - Transcript](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/SGU_1.02_%22Air_Part_2%22_Transcript)</sup></sub>

As a side note, ascending would have also answered the question that the Ancients designed the Destiny to answer.

Comment: Rush may have been assuming things. If nothing else Ascended Ancients may have made that trip long ago or followed *them* to Destiny. Not only Rush's "head" Franklin but also several of the people he interacted with while plugged into the chair had a definite "ascended" feel. It kind of blurs the line on what constitutes crew.

Answer (score 26):

## An engineering team was trapped aboard *Destiny*, and the planned expedition team never arrived

In *Stargate Universe: Back to Destiny* (a canon comic book followup to Season 2), [issue 1](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_Universe:_Back_to_Destiny_1) shows Eli traveling to an unexplored section of the ship where there are stasis pods containing Ancients.

[image: Stargate Universe: Back to Destiny, Issue 1: Eli discovers Ancients in stasis pods]

In [issue 2](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_Universe:_Back_to_Destiny_2), these Ancients explain that they were engineers preparing *Destiny* for launch, and that there was another team designated for the actual expedition mission.

[image: Stargate Universe: Back to Destiny, Issue 2: Vasi explains that her team are engineers, not explorers]

> Vasi. My name is *Vasi*. It was not *our* mission. We are engineers, *not* explorers.

She later recounts what happened, explaining that there was a last minute malfunction before *Destiny* launched that trapped them aboard and unable to leave through the Stargate. They were ordered to go into the stasis pods and await rescue from the expedition team, but they never arrived and they don't know why.

[image: Stargate Universe: Back to Destiny, Issue 2: Vasi explains in a flashback how her team was trapped on Destiny]

> Vasi (flashback): Then what are we supposed to do?
>
> Superior (flashback, via audio): *Repair* the power systems in your section and take *refuge* in hibernation pods. When the *expedition team* arrives, you will return through the Astria Porta [Stargate].
>
> Eli: So what *did* you do?
>
> Vasi: We followed orders. Now, as rescue would seem to be a million years in the past, we are trapped here with no way home.
>
> Eli: For what it's worth, *that's* something we have in common.

So we know from someone with firsthand knowledge that *Destiny* was intended to have an expedition team for accomplishing the ship's mission, but we don't know why they didn't arrive to rescue the Ancient engineers who were trapped aboard.

Comment: Good find. These guys aren't exactly the crew (more of a shakedown team) but they're close enough in my book.

Comment: @Valorum Yup, they make it clear that a different, permanent crew was supposed to arrive as part of the mission, but they didn't make it for unknown reasons.

Comment: If she's an engineer **on her own ship**, why does she have a gun?  Enquiring minds want to know!

Comment: @RonJohn They later find lots of supplies on the ship that were intended for the exploration team. Given that she doesn't have a sidearm in the flashback before going into stasis, I presume she got the gun from that stash.